# autoref names messed up when defining certain ntheorem theoremstyles

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, theorems, ntheorem

I define a theorem style pretty innocuously, to get things looking a bit more like amsthm theorems. But - my `\autoref{}`s become messed up with optional arguments of theorem environments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{nicestyle}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep {\theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2}{\normalfont\ (##3)}
   {\theorem@headerfont \theorem@separator}]}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{nicestyle}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
\label{lem:first}
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}[Apple]
\label{lem:second}
The second brown fox jumped over the second dog.
\end{lemma}

I want to refer to the two lemmata above, and should be getting
``Lemma 0.1'' and ``Lemma 0.2''. But autoref gives me ``Apple 0.1''
and ``Apple 0.2'': \autoref{lem:first} and \autoref{lem:second}.

\end{document}
```

And the output:
[image: output]

Am I doing something wrong or is this an `ntheorem` bug? (using MikTex 2.9).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hyperref mentions something to this effect in the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf) (p 15). To avoid this, you can 'suggest' what `\autoref` should use by means of

```
\theoremstyle{nicestyle}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\providecommand*{\lemmaautorefname}{Lemma}
```

[image: Forcing \autoref to pick the right name]

Comment: It works... I actually tried `\providecommand*` before, but without the star, so that didn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Load
`\usepackage[thref,hyperref]{ntheorem}`
and change the references into
`\thref{lem:first}` and `\thref{lem:second}`.

`\autoref` is a `hyperref` command, so it might well collide
with `ntheorem`'s way of communicating information to the
second compilation pass via the `.aux` and `.thm` files.

The adaptation towards `hyperref` is a kind of hack, as `hyperref`
forces its definitions at `\AtBeginDocument`.

Comment: What's the benefit of using \thref in general? Or rather - where do I read about \thref vs \autoref ? Are they supposed to behave the same (specifically, does \thref create a clickable link in the PDF)?